# entityQuery filter by content moderation state

Tags: 8, nodes

I need to filter a node by moderation state. I am using the Drupal 8 content moderation module.

I basically want to get NIDs of all nodes in draft state. Something similar to this.

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('moderation_state', 'draft')
      ->execute();
```

Answer (score 5):

An additional workaround to this is you can add a tag to the entity query and then alter it in a separate `hook_query_TAG_alter` hook. It's an extra step but it gets the job done and gives you direct access to the SQL query for you to modify. So you can generate the entity query like you normally would, and any extra SQL that it does not support you can modify as needed.

Entity query:

```
/** @var \Drupal\node\NodeStorage $storage */
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$query = $storage->getQuery()
  ->addTag('archive_press_releases')
  ->currentRevision()
  ->condition('type', ['post_page', 'story_page'], 'IN')
  ->condition('field_date', $formatted, '<=')
  ->sort('field_date');
$result = $query->execute();
```

hook_query_TAG_alter example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 */
function bax_archiving_query_archive_press_releases_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->addJoin('LEFT', 'content_moderation_state_field_data', 'md', 'md.content_entity_revision_id = base_table.vid');
  $query->condition('md.moderation_state', 'archived', '<>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it almost worked for me. It lacks the eventual control on the node language (if translation is also enabled) and it may give unwanted result in the case nodes are moved from `archived` to another not-default state, e.g. `draft`. This latter case is problematic is one want to exclude only `archived` nodes in the latest revision. I've add an example for a case with those two condition.

Answer (score 3):

You try the code :

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('content_moderation_state_field_data', 'ms');
    $query->join('node_field_revision', 'nf', 'nf.nid=ms.content_entity_id AND nf.vid=ms.content_entity_revision_id AND nf.langcode=ms.langcode');
    $query->fields('ms');
    $query->condition('ms.moderation_state','draft');
    $results = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('content_entity_id');
```

Because `entityQuery` not filter content moderation

Comment: Just to add more information about this entityQuery limitation. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3025164

Answer (score 1):

Posting a link to the d.o issue queue where as of this week a *potential patch* to core to allow `EntityQuery` to recognize Workflow moderation state that @Santiago cited above:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3025164#comment-13221005
Without this patch or a similar core hack, EntityQuery can not query Drupal 8 Workflow moderation state.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Lester Peabody almost worked for me.

However, it could gives unwanted results, depending the logic you expect.

1. `archived` state by default settings is a *default revision* state, therefore querying for `currentRevision()` nodes will count also the ones which have another not-default moderation state.
   E.g.:a node has been `archived` and later moved again in `draft` With that query that node *will be counted*. In the case this is not wanted, it's better to query against nodes' latest revision.
2. It doesn't consider the case the eventual translation.

If 1. and 2. are legit cases then the coode is:

```php
function example() {
    $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();

    return $query->addTag('example_tag')
      ->latestRevision()
      ->condition('type', 'node_type')
      ->condition('langcode', 'en')
      ->execute();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 */
function hook_query_example_tag_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->addJoin('LEFT', 'content_moderation_state_field_revision', 'md', 'md.content_entity_revision_id = base_table.vid AND md.langcode = base_table.langcode');
  $query->condition('md.moderation_state', 'archived', '<>');
}
```